# Dell OpenManage Server Administrator - doesn't display storage devices

Tags: centos, raid, dell, dell-poweredge, dell-openmanage

I'm running CentOS 5 on a Dell PowerEdge R200. I have installed OpenManage Server Administrator specifically to monitor the HDDs (x2 250GB RAID1) in the machine and alert of any issues or failures.

I have also installed the SAS 5/iR / 6/iR Device driver as the machine has SATA2 HDDs, being an R200.

However, I can't get the storage devices to display in the OMSA web interface. I can't find the answer anywhere else so I am wondering if any of you guys have experienced the same issue before.

Thank you in advance,

Flick.

::UPDATE::

upon restarting all the services as suggested below by David, the following occurs:

```
[root@xx ~]# for i in dsm_om_shrsvc instsvcdrv dataeng dsm_om_connsvc ; do service $i stop  ; done
Shutting down DSM SA Shared Services:                      [  OK  ]

Stopping Systems Management Data Engine:
Stopping dsm_sa_snmp32d:                                   [  OK  ]
Stopping dsm_sa_eventmgr32d:                               [  OK  ]
Stopping dsm_sa_datamgr32d:                                [  OK  ]
Stopping Systems Management Device Drivers:
Stopping dell_rbu:                                         [  OK  ]
Stopping Systems Management Data Engine:
Stopping dsm_sa_snmp32d: Not started                       [FAILED]
Stopping dsm_sa_eventmgr32d: Not started                   [FAILED]
Stopping dsm_sa_datamgr32d: Not started                    [FAILED]
Shutting down DSM SA Connection Service:                   [  OK  ]

[root@xx ~]# for i in dsm_om_shrsvc instsvcdrv dataeng dsm_om_connsvc ; do service $i start ; done
Starting DSM SA Shared Services:                           [  OK  ]
Starting Systems Management Device Drivers:
Starting dell_rbu:                                         [  OK  ]
Starting ipmi driver: Already started                      [  OK  ]
Starting Systems Management Data Engine:
Starting dsm_sa_datamgr32d:                                [  OK  ]
Starting dsm_sa_eventmgr32d:                               [  OK  ]
Starting dsm_sa_snmp32d:                                   [  OK  ]
Starting DSM SA Connection Service:                        [  OK  ]
```

as you can see, dsm_sa_snmp32d, dsm_sa_eventmgr32d, dsm_sa_datamgr32d were not started in the first place and when I start all services they do start. However when I run the stop loop again, they are already stopped.

::UPDATE 2::
actually, according to the service status of each apparently stopped service, they are in fact running so the above may not be relevant.

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved it, I think. When installing OMSA, be sure to install ALL components, ie. the following:

```
[x] Server Administrator CLI
[x] Server Administrator Web Server
[x] Storage Management
```

If you neglect to install storage management, chances are you wont be able to manage storage devices :)

Now I just need to find out if I can get it to email alerts to me. Thanks all!

Flick

Comment: If you're PERC drivers are out of date it will also helpfully deselect the Storage option for you as well

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me, too - you might check to see that you have the latest firmware on the physical disks involved.  Updating this solved the problem, though after I had pulled all of my hair out and called Dell.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, sometimes the OMSA doesn't start properly.  I could never figure out why.

My method is to have this script available to the root user, if you run it then (usually) the OMSA pieces run and you can get the information you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in dsm_om_shrsvc instsvcdrv dataeng dsm_om_connsvc ; do service $i stop  ; done
sleep 5
for i in dsm_om_shrsvc instsvcdrv dataeng dsm_om_connsvc ; do service $i start ; done
```

Comment: thank you very much :)
I restarted all the services and the storage devices still don't display. Do you know if this definitely should be working with SAS 5/iR / 6/iR devices?

thanks